# Error while placing a spinner and Date Picker together inside Activity Group

Tags: android, datepicker, spinner, activitygroup

Initially I was not able to add spinner inside an activity group I was getting the following error

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(474): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@43791b18 is not valid; is your activity running?
```

This got fixed after I put the following piece of code

```
View viewToLoad = LayoutInflater.from(this.getParent()).inflate(R.layout.rem_data2, null);
setContentView(viewToLoad);
```

But this solution does not work when I add more windows to the child screen. for example when i add a datepicker along with a spinner I get the same error again but this time it is for date picker.

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(474): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@43791b18 is not valid; is your activity running?
```

I am stuck here, any hint wil be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution by adding getParent() instead of this inside the switch statement then it works :)

```
 switch (id) {
 case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
     return new DatePickerDialog(getParent(),
                 mDateSetListener,
                 mYear, mMonth, mDay);
 case DATE_DIALOG_ID_RETURN:
     return new DatePickerDialog(getParent(),
       mDateSetListenerreturn,
                 mYear, mMonth, mDay);     
 }
```

I got this solution from [Android: DatePicker not working inside Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976818/android-datepicker-not-working-inside-actvity) answered by Mathieu