# datepicker in child activity of activitygroup raises BadTokenException error

Tags: android, datepicker, activitygroup

I need to display two datepickers in a child activity of an activitygroup in a tabbed activity.
the code for the two textviews and to buttons to display the date is:

```
  incorp_date=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.edt_incorpdate);
    incorp_date_image=(Button)findViewById(R.id.incorp_date);


    incorp_date_cal=Calendar.getInstance();

    incorp_date_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DATE_PICKER_INCORP);
        }
    });

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    incorp_year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    incorp_month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    incorp_day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    /* display the current date (this method is below)  */
    updateIncorpDisplay();


    estb_date=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.edt_estabdate);
    estb_date_image=(Button)findViewById(R.id.estb_date);
    estb_date_cal=Calendar.getInstance();

    estb_date_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DATE_PICKER_ESTB);
        }
    });
    final Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    estb_year = c1.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    estb_month = c1.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    estb_day = c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    /* display the current date (this method is below)  */
    updateEstbDisplay();
```

the code to display the datepicker dialog is:

```
incorp_dateListener=new OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            incorp_year = year;
            incorp_month = monthOfYear;
            incorp_day = dayOfMonth;
            updateIncorpDisplay();
        }
    };

    estb_dateListener=new OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            estb_year = year;
            estb_month = monthOfYear;
            estb_day = dayOfMonth;
            updateEstbDisplay();
        }
    };
  @Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    switch(id){
        case DATE_PICKER_INCORP:
                return new DatePickerDialog(getParent(), incorp_dateListener, incorp_year, incorp_month, incorp_day); 
            case DATE_PICKER_ESTB:
                return new DatePickerDialog(getParent(), estb_dateListener, estb_year, estb_month, estb_day);
    }
        return null;
}
```

I am not able to display the datepicker dialog.
the application force closes when i click the button and an exception of BadTokenException is raised..
what should i do??? I cant seem to figure out what the problem is??? 
I think maybe its because its a child activity of an activitygroup..
but cant find any relevant solution..
Please help!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Something like this,First you create **tabcontext** object in your **TabActivity** Class.like this

```
package com.loanreminder;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

/**
 * @author Adil Soomro
 * 
 */
public class TabSample extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    public static TabSample tabContext;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabhost);
        tabContext = this;

    }

}
```

After Use this Object Like this in Your activity.

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

    switch(id){
        case DATE_PICKER_INCORP:
                return new DatePickerDialog(TabSample.tabContext, incorp_dateListener, incorp_year, incorp_month, incorp_day); 
            case DATE_PICKER_ESTB:
                return new DatePickerDialog(TabSample.tabContext, estb_dateListener, estb_year, estb_month, estb_day);
    }
        return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this

> ```
>      switch (id) {
> case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
>  return new DatePickerDialog(getParent(),
>              mDateSetListener,
>              mYear, mMonth, mDay);
> case DATE_DIALOG_ID_RETURN:
>  return new DatePickerDialog(getParent(),
>    mDateSetListenerreturn,
>              mYear, mMonth, mDay);     
>  }
> ```

I got this solution from [Android: DatePicker not working inside Actvity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976818/android-datepicker-not-working-inside-activity)